# Ionic article sample with Backend service

Tags: php, ionic-framework

Can anybody please introduce me an article or sample code for ionic framework , which has PHP Service code and simple example of listing some information from database from service side into application? I specially need to study the PHP part too so I can see how they manage all the parts. There are many sample ionic application in their website but I need something simple and don't know which one is good and easy for learning and study ( and also contain PHP service code ).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please read follwing articles this may help you ,

1. [Posting data from Ionic app to PHP server](http://www.nikola-breznjak.com/blog/codeproject/posting-data-from-ionic-app-to-php-server/) , Source Code are [here](https://github.com/Hitman666/IonicServerSave).
2. [File Upload & Download With ng-cordova File Transfer Plugin In Ionic Framework](http://www.santoshshinde.com/2015/03/file-upload-download-with-ng-cordova.html) , Source Code are [here](https://github.com/santoshshinde2012/FileTransfer_Upload).
3. [Ionic-FB-Login-PHP-MySQL-DB-AdMob](https://github.com/AnupKumarPanwar/Ionic-FB-Login-PHP-MySQL-DB-AdMob)
4. [PHP in the Ionic framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35783266/obtaining-a-json-array-from-php-via-javascript-in-the-ionic-framework)
5. [angularjs, ionic, and json decode using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37433110/angularjs-ionic-and-json-decode-using-php)
6. [Angular Post Request to PHP](https://codeforgeek.com/2014/07/angular-post-request-php/)

Hope this will help you !!

Comment: thanks for your answer, the first one talks about sending data to PHP server, whatabout the other way? Sending data from PHP server to Ionic app? Becasue my first step is get data FROM server :)

Comment: Please check the link 4 ,5 and6